# How to display Json data in JavaFX

Tags: json, javafx-2

My JavaFX application handles large amounts Json data. How do I visualize the simplest way JSON data in a table that also must be editable?

The obvious method is to convert JSON to Java objects but for a number of reasons I would like to avoid that.

UPDATE, from comment below I have tried this(feeding ListView directly).

```
string json = "[{\"fields\":{\"VENDOR\":[\"xxx""],\"TYPE\":[\"yyyyy\"]}, \"path\": \"C:\"}]"; 
@FXML
private ListView idListView;
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json));
public JsonArray myItems = reader.readArray();
reader.close();
public ObservableList<JsonObject> olist;
oList = FXCollections.observableArrayList((JsonObject[])myItems.toArray())
idListView.setItems(oList);
```

Not working for me. What can I do diffently?

/regards
//lg

Comment: uhmm you can use a listview, it can take care of that, but also you can persist it call a reasonable number to the json

Comment: Dont understand what you mean.

Comment: use the json object as the source data for a ListView.. that is what i mean

Comment: You may convert the json data to map and follow [Example 12-12 Adding Map Data to the Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CEGHGDFA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this advise "You may convert the json data to map and follow Example 12-12 Adding Map Data to the Table. –  Uluk Biy Jun 5 at 9:05"